# Silverstripe 4 save variable in database

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Is posible to save SS template variable in database from CMS  and after execute it in template?

Okay lets see example:
In CMS i have settings where i put social media links and contact informatios.
Also in CMS i have module where i create HTML block-s which after that i loop in website.

In that html block i want to put existing $SiteConfig.Email variable.

I Try that but that is rendered in template like $SiteConfig.Email not show real email?

Is this posible to do or i need some extra modification?

Check photo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question you have written makes no sense to me, but I understand the screenshot.

So, SilverStripe renders `.ss` files with a class called `SSViewer`. Basically it reads the file as string and then runs it through SSViewer to generate the HTML output.
But, as you saw, the output of variables is not processed.

I can think of 3 ways to get what you want:

1. Run the variables through SSViewer aswell (in this example, use `$RenderedHTMLContent` in the template)

```php
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
  private static array $db = [
    'Title' => DBVarchar::class,
    'HTMLContent' => DBText::class,
  ];

  public function Foobar() { return "hello from foobar"; }

  public function RenderedHTMLContent() {
    $template = \SilverStripe\View\SSViewer::fromString($this->HTMLContent);
    // using $this->renderWith() will allow you access to all things of $this in the template. so eg $ID, $Title or $Foobar. Probably also $SiteConfig because it's global
    return $this->renderWith($template);
    // if you want to add extra variables that are not part of $this, you can also do:
    return $this->renderWith($template, ["ExtraVariable" => "Hello from extra variable"]);
    // if you do not want $this, you can do:
    return (new ArrayData(["MyVariable" => "my value"]))->renderWith($template);
  }
}
```

**Please be aware of the security implications this thing brings. SilverStripe is purposely built to not allow content authors to write template files. A content author can not only call the currently scoped object but also all global template variables. This includes $SiteConfig, $List, .... Therefore a "bad" content author can write a template like `<% loop $List('SilverStripe\Security\Member') %>$ID $FirstName $LastName $Email $Salt $Password<% end_loop %>` or perhaps might access methods that have file access. So only do this if you trust your content authors**

2. Use shortcodes instead of variables. But I never liked shortcodes, so I don't remember how they work. You'll have to lookup the docs for that.
3. Build your own mini template system with str_replace.

```php
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
  private static array $db = [
    'Title' => DBVarchar::class,
    'HTMLContent' => DBText::class,
  ];

  public function Foobar() { return "hello from foobar"; }

  public function RenderedHTMLContent() {
    return str_replace(
       [
         '$SiteConfig.Title', 
         '$SiteConfig.Tagline',
         '$Title',
         '$Foobar',
       ],
       [
         SiteConfig::current_site_config()->Title,
         SiteConfig::current_site_config()->Tagline,
         $this->Title,
         $this->Foobar(),
       ],
       $this->HTMLContent
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow shortcodes i cant beleve how i forget for that??? i Read now doc for shortcodes and i think that can slove my problem.